# Update listview items when datasource changes

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml

I have a list that I use as a log. I want to see the log in a listview therefor I have created:

```
 <ListView Margin="12,114,12,12" Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

The log gets populated with a field on a class that I did not create, so there is a class as:

```
SomeClass
{

     public ReadOnlyCollection<Status> Log
     {
         get
         {
              return _log.AsReadOnly();
         }
     }

     // other method and fields
     // etc...

}
```

so I am able to see the list items. Moreover, I am able to populate the listview with this log as:

```
listView1.DataContext = server.Log;   // server is an instance of SomeClass
```

the only problem is that every time the log changes the listview does not update. I have to call listView1.DataContext = server.Log; every time I wish to refresh the log.

how can I avoid having to refresh the listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `ObservableCollection<Status>` instead of a `ReadOnlyCollection<Status>`

The reason for this is that Observable collection notifies the controls it is bound to whenever an item is added/removed.

If you want each `Status` object to notify the view when one of their property changes (so a property in a `Status` instance changes, but there is no add/remove on the collection), then `Status` has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and each Property needs to raise the `PropertyChanged` event on its setter.

You can do all this via [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759216/implementation-of-composition-and-aggregation-in-c) also, if it's a third-party dll.

Sidenote: why do you have a `Margin` above 100? you should use ContentPresenters such as `Grid` or `StackPanels`

Comment: that class is actually a dll so I am not able to modify it. If I could then I would fire an event every time the log changes....