# association, aggregation and composition example

Tags: oop

**association, aggregation and composition**

I want to get the illustration for above three with simple classes. I read a lot from internet. The conclusion is as-

In aggregation people say-

"Class A contains collection of another Class (say B) and if A is destroyed it will not affect its child that is collection will not be destroyed."
How is it possible if one object is destroyed but its property can still exist or what they mean by this.(Am I misinterpreting something)

```
Class A
{
List<B> lst;
}

Class B
{

}
```

Comment: There are many questions in so on this. Did you try them

Comment: yes checked.....but couldn't get it....so hope to get something in context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between aggregation, composition and dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644273/what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write Composition and Aggregation in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862286/how-to-write-composition-and-aggregation-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following classes,

```
class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Department
{
    public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void RemoveStudent(Student student)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

If you want to add a student to the department, then you call `AddStudent()` and pass the **reference** of the `Student` class instance (note that a reference is passed). So when the department instance is destroyed (set to `null` for example), then the `Students` property of that `Department` instance is no longer available, but the `Student` instances that have been used to populate this list remain are not destroyed. Hence, the property, in this case a `Student` instance can still exist.

**More information**

- [implementation of composition and aggregation in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759216/implementation-of-composition-and-aggregation-in-c)
- [C# Tutorial - Aggregation and Composition](http://www.publicjoe.f9.co.uk/csharp/tut/csharp04m.html)
- [Difference between Composition and Aggregation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/compagg07272007062838AM/compagg.aspx)

Comment: thanks Devendra!! nice links you provided...looks like I need to explore more from net...BTW...nice explanation.