# How to write Composition and Aggregation in java

Tags: java, c++, oop

I want to know how to identify composition and aggregation code in java. I have C++ Code, But I don't understand how to write in java.

Composition

```
class A {};
class B { A composited_A; };
```

Aggregation via Pointer

```
class A {};
class B
{
A* pointer_to_A;
B(A anA){ 
pointer_to_A = &anA;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how both are working in JAVA. (I know what is meant by Composition and aggregation )
    };

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java itself simply does not make the distinction between composition and aggregation. You cannot express the idea of ownership of a reference in the Java type system – if you explicitly need to express ownership you must denote this with some other means (usually simply by constructing a new object to be stored in the instance of a class).

Since Java has a GC, ownership for memory doesn’t need to be expressed at all; memory is owned and managed solely by the GC. Of course, the same is not true for other resources and here you might still want to express ownership.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, objects are only referenced by pointers. This means that a field of type `A` is really a reference to an `A` object. It also means that that field will always start as a null pointer, and you must explicitly assign it to `new A()` or whatever.

**Edit:**

```
class B {
   A a;

   B(A a) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   B() {
      this(new A());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this aggregation?.

Comment: It depends on how you use `a`. Normally, if the intention is composition, you make `a` be `final` so that it will never change, and then you ensure it is assigned a non-null value in the constructor. If the intention is aggregation, you might provide a `setA()` method to change `a`.

Comment: Thanks once again. Now its clear. this link also example. I want to know where is it correct.[link](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=20)[link]

Comment: Making the reference pointer to field `a` `final` does not narrow the aggregation to composition. The object still doesn't die when the enclosing instance of `B` dies.

Comment: Hmm. That defines it in terms of `A`, where it is composition only if `A` exists only as a part of `B`. I consider it composition if `A` is a permanent and necessary part of `B`, even if `A` can exist also on its own or as part of another class. I'm not sure which is right.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is best way to express Composition and Aggregation With Java Code.

**Composition**

```
public class Person  
{  
    private final Name name;  

    public Person (String fName, String lName)  
    {  
        name = new Name(fName, lName);  
    }  

    //...  
}
```

**Aggregation**

```
public class Person  
{  
    private Costume currentClothes;  

    public void setClothes(Costume clothes)  
    {  
        currentClothes = clothes;  
    }  

    //...  
}
```

[Source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/522414/java/java/Association-Vs-Aggregation-Vs-Composition#post_text_2366494)